# What is the VBA code for putting cell data from one worksheet to another worksheet that includes text?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I am trying to add data from another cell on another sheet to an existing cell with text.
The cell A1 should read, "Pay Summary #" and then the code from Q9 offset by 1 or Q10.

I cannot get the last part of the formula to display the information from Q10.  Here is what I have so far:

Sub Add_info()
'
'

```
PayRequestNumber = Sheets("Billing Summary").Range("Q9").Offset(1, 0)

Sheets("1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "'" & "Pay Summary #" & =PayRequestNumber"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT]: After getting some more information about the request, give this code a try:

```
Sub Add_Sub_Page()

    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
    Dim strSheetName As String
    Dim lPayRequestNumber As Long

    Set wsTemplate = Sheets("Template")
    lPayRequestNumber = Sheets("Billing Summary").Range("Q10").Value
    strSheetName = Sheets("Invoice Summary").Range("T10").Value

    If Evaluate("ISREF('" & strSheetName & "'!A1)") Then
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & strSheetName & "' already exists.", , "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    wsTemplate.Copy Before:=Sheets(8)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = strSheetName
        .Range("A1").Value = "Pay Summary # " & lPayRequestNumber
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the PayRequestNumber in the formula?  I plan to use this to add a new sheet and would like to stick with Active.Sheet instead of the "Sheet "1" named range.

Comment: `PayRequestNumber = Sheets("Billing Summary").Range("Q10").Value
Sheets("1").Range("A1").Value = "Pay Summary # " & PayRequestNumber`

Comment: Though I would have to recommend against using ActiveSheet syntax.  It can be confusing to read/interpret and it is not efficient because you have to Select/Activate each sheet you're working on, instead of writing to them directly

Comment: If you really wanted to though, just replace the Sheets("1") with ActiveSheet

Comment: The  "& PayRequestNumber" didn't seem to bring back the info from the other sheet (Billing Summary).

Comment: It works for me just fine, can you post the code that's not working?  Also, what is in cell 'Billing Summary'!Q10 ?

Comment: The value for PayRequestNumber = Sheets("Invoice Summary").Range("Q9").Offset(1, 0) is 2.  The code changed a bit...  But the question is the same.  I will post it in the next window.

Comment: Sub Add_Sub_Page()
'
' Add_Sub Macro
'

    PayRequestNumber = Sheets("Billing Summary").Range("Q9").Offset(1, 0)
    SheetName = Sheets("Invoice Summary").Range("T9").Offset(1, 0)
    
    ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Sheets(8)
 
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Pay Summary #" & PayRequestNumber

Comment: Sorry for the format... please let me know if there is a better way to post.

Comment: In that cod eyou have `ActiveSheet.Select` and then you make a copy the active sheet.  Is the ActiveSheet supposed to be some sort of template?

Comment: Yes...  not an official template, but wanting to replicate an existing sheet with a few modifications.

Comment: I have edited my answer.  You can (and should) have a worksheet named "Template" (which can be hidden if preferred).  The code shows how to copy it and update values.  I have tested the code and it runs as expected with test data.